# Question about affine connections on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, affine-geometry, information-geometry

I am reading Information geometry by "Amari" and I am having a problem understanding how the author defined the following linear map,

Intuitively, defining an affine connection on a manifold $S$ means that for each point $p\in S$ and its "neighbor" $p'$, we define a linear one-to-one mapping between $T_p$ and $T_{p'}$. Here we call $p'$ a neighbor of $p$ if, given a coordinate system $[\xi^i]$ of $S$, the difference between the coordinates of $p$ and $p'$, $d\xi^i=\xi^i(p')-\xi^i(p)$. when construed as a first-order infinitesimal, is sufficiently small that we may ignore the second-order infinitesimals $(d\xi^i)(d\xi^j)$. Below we shall introduce the notion of affine connections in an intuitive manner using infinitesimals.

In order to establish a linear mapping $\prod_{p,p'}$ between $T_P$, and $T_{p'}$, we must specify, for each $j\in\{1,2,......,n\}$, how to express  $\prod_{p,p'}((\partial_{j})_p)$ in terms of a linear combination of $\{(\partial_1)_{p'},....,(\partial_n)_{p'}\}$ where $\partial_j=\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^j}$. Let us def assume that the difference between $\prod_{p,p'}((\partial_{j})_p)$ and $(\partial_j)_{p'}$ , is infinitesimal. and that it may be expressed as a linear combination of $\{d\xi^1,....,d\xi^n\}$. Then we have
$\prod_{p,p'}((\partial_{j})_p)=(\partial_j)_p'-d\xi^i(\Gamma_{ij}^{k})_{p}(\partial_k)_{p'}$

where $\{(\Gamma_{ij}^{k})_{p};i,j,k=1,...,n\}$ are $n³$ real numbers which depend on the point $p$ and $p'$ in $S$.
I am stuck here and do not get any idea about how this map is defined. If someone explains it that will be a great help.

Comment: A connection does give you an isomorphism $\Pi_{p,p'}\colon T_p \to T_{p'}$ from the data of $p$ and $p'$. It gives you an isomorphism $\Pi_{p,p',\gamma} \colon T_p\to T_{p'}$ from the data of $p,p'$ and a path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to S$ joining $p$ and $p'$. It highly depends on the path $\gamma$. It is the so called parallel transport **along** $\gamma$.

Comment: and how $\prod_{p,p'}((\partial_{j})_p)=(\partial_j)_p'-d\xi^i(\Gamma_{ij}^{k})_{p}(\partial_k)_{p'}$ this map is defined?

Comment: Ok I see. The author seems to choose 'the straight line in the coordinate system' for the path $\gamma$ in my previous comment. Not that this explanation from the author is really heuristic and not totally rigorous: it is just for you to "feel" the construction

Comment: yes,here we are choosing straight line after this the author introduces path $\gamma$